# Using iTextSharp and AddDocument/FreeReader to create a PDF document in streaming fashion

Tags: c#, pdf

I have a directory of PDF files I want to merge into a single PDF.  The number of files in the directory could be 10s, 100s, or even 1000s, so I'm trying to make sure my process is streaming as much as possible.

`MergePDFDocuments` is passed an output `Stream` and I'm hoping the process below never has more than 1 PDF file loaded in memory at a time.

I had an incorrect version of this written originally, and was told on [my Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370143/merge-pdf-files-using-itextsharp-into-output-stream) not to use `PdfWriter` but instead use `PdfSmartCopy`.  Is `FreeReader()` going to release memory consumed by each PDF file as it is processed?

```
private void MergePDFDocuments( string batchFilesFolder, Stream outputStream )
{
    using ( var batchDocument = new iTextSharp.text.Document() )
    using ( var smartCopy = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy( batchDocument, outputStream ) )
    {
        batchDocument.Open();

        foreach ( var file in new DirectoryInfo( batchFilesFolder ).GetFiles( "*.pdf" ) )
        {
            // we create a reader for the document
            using ( var reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader( file.FullName ) )
            {
                smartCopy.AddDocument( reader );
                smartCopy.FreeReader( reader );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks more like a question to the creators of `iTextSharp`.

Comment: Since you have `reader` in a `using` it is going to be disposed *at some point*. This may only happen when there is memory pressure and the GC needs to run. You can try to force this by calling `GC.Collect()` but is almost always a bad idea (at the very least, it will significantly slow your program down). My suggestion is to run it through a memory profiler, you'll probably see the memory climb until the GC runs. [Here is a good read on .NET Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just use/watch Task Monitor memory usage?  Or better memory profiler?  Admittedly, I've never done any memory profiling.  Probably something built into VS - will dig around looking.